# NTPD: how to protect the connection of client with a Symmetric key?

Tags: linux, ntp

I'm trying to use symmetric key when I sync the time and because it's for a product of my company, I can only use the command "ntpd", so no commands like "ntpq" for more information.

Here is what I've done:
1) sync time without authentication key, it works
2) then **ntp-gen** to generate MD5 key file at server side

```
   /tmp/ntp.keys
   2 MD5 N6\VRj&\t96tl]Xb@%$^  # MD5 key        
   3 MD5 M_4ga}||b_WM@te[\S33  # MD5 key
```

3) pick up one line and add to **ntp.keys** at client side

```
 /tmp/ntp.keys    
 2 MD5 N6\VRj&\t96tl]Xb@%$^  # MD5 key
```

4) ntp.conf at server side

```
broadcast 10.66.208.26 key 2    

keys /tmp/ntp.keys
trustedkey 2
requestkey 2
controlkey 2
```

5) ntp.conf at client side

```
server 10.66.208.122
```

6) command to syn time:

```
ntpd -a -k /tmp/ntp.keys -g -q -d -c /tmp/ntp.conf
```

because of the OS conception, we use only ** -a ** to active authentication check, without key number.

7) then the output:
   the problem is at the end: no servers found. I cannot understand, since there is "transmit" and "receive"

```
ntpd 4.2.6p3@1.2290 Thu Sep  4 21:36:24 UTC 2014 (2)    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: proto: precision = 3.875 usec        
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c01d 0d kern kernel time sync enabled    
Finished Parsing!!    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket    boundary: 16    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123    
restrict: op 1 addr 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 3 wan2 10.66.208.26 UDP 123    
restrict: op 1 addr 10.66.208.26 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 0000001    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 4 iloc 192.168.0.1 UDP 123    
restrict: op 1 addr 192.168.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 mflags 00003000 flags 00000001    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 5 lo ::1 UDP 123    
restrict: op 1 addr ::1 mask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff mflags 00003000 flags 00000001    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 6 wan2 fe80::7e66:9dff:fe12:3fd UDP 123        
restrict: op 1 addr fe80::7e66:9dff:fe12:3fd mask     ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff mflags 00003000 flags 00000001          
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 7 iloc fe80::7e66:9dff:fe12:3ff UDP 123        
restrict: op 1 addr fe80::7e66:9dff:fe12:3ff mask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff     mflags 00003000 flags 00000001    
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listen normally on 8 plc0 fe80::1010:ff:fe00:0 UDP 123        
restrict: op 1 addr fe80::1010:ff:fe00:0 mask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff   mflags 00003000 flags 00000001         
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: peers refreshed          
5 Sep 16:10:42 ntpd[4958]: Listening on routing socket on fd #25 for interface updates
peer_clear: at 0 next 1 associd 53920 refid INIT     
event at 0 10.66.208.122 8011 81 mobilize assoc 53920     
newpeer: 10.66.208.26->10.66.208.122 mode 3 vers 4 poll 6 10 flags 0x101 0x1 ttl 0 key  00000000    
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart     
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM     
event at 0 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set     
transmit: at 1 10.66.208.26->10.66.208.122 mode 3 len 48       
receive: at 13 10.66.208.26<-10.66.208.122 mode 4 len 48      
packet: flash header 1420      
transmit: at 15 10.66.208.26->10.66.208.122 mode 3 len 48      
receive: at 15 10.66.208.26<-10.66.208.122 mode 4 len 48     
packet: flash header 1420     
transmit: at 17 10.66.208.26->10.66.208.122 mode 3 len 48     
receive: at 17 10.66.208.26<-10.66.208.122 mode 4 len 48     
packet: flash header 1420     
transmit: at 19 10.66.208.26->10.66.208.122 mode 3 len 48      
receive: at 19 10.66.208.26<-10.66.208.122 mode 4 len 48     
packet: flash header 1420     
transmit: at 21 10.66.208.26->10.66.208.122 mode 3 len 48      
receive: at 21 10.66.208.26<-10.66.208.122 mode 4 len 48      
packet: flash header 1420      
5 Sep 16:11:05 ntpd[4958]: ntpd: no servers found     
ntpd: no servers found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ntp.keys` file might be off.  Instead of `MD5` for the key type, you want `M`.

```
/tmp/ntp.keys
2 M N6\VRj&\t96tl]Xb@%$^  # MD5 key        
3 M M_4ga}||b_WM@te[\S33  # MD5 key
```

Check out ntp.org [here](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config.htm#Q-CONF-REMOTE-ADMIN).